# How to join edges in SUMO?

Tags: sumo

I have an opendrive file which I converted into a sumo network file. I would like to modify some sections of the roads but there are multiple edges close to each other and sometimes overlaps. I tried many commands: --geometry.avoid-overlap --edges.join --junctions.join --geometry.remove but it still does not work. The edges still appear as in the image [image: road_with_edges]. How can I combine them to be just one edge instead? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If netconvert does not join the edges there is a reason for that. Probably they are different in some attribute. You should have a look at the options `--geometry.remove.min-length` (merge short edges even if they differ in attributes) and `--geometry.remove.width-tolerance` (merge edges which only differ in width) which allow to override this mechanism.